# Deducting the price from one company to another in QuickBook

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I would like to know if it is possible to create two company profiles in QuickBooks and be able to automatically reduce stock and pricing from one company to the another?

So assume company (a) has the default list with pricing. When creating company (b) it should automatically replicate everything from company (a) and then apply a different set of prices?

When stock reduces on company (b) it should be reflected in company (a)

I may have over simplied the problem here.

My friend has wholesal and retail businesses .in the same premises.  Uses QuickBooks for both but with seperate installations on different laptops. So effectively he adjusts the prices on both manually.

He is installing an EPOS system that can connect with QuickBooks for the retail businesses (remotely).  If he could connect both of the company profiles in one single QuickBook and do the above it would be super efficient for him.

He uses the desktop version and if need be can move to the online version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at QBSDK. As REST endpoints are deprecated, so I think, QBSDK is the only solution for this usecase.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0060_sdk_components

Thanks

Comment: Appreciate you coming back to me.  Will now source a developer to explore this for us